# EF Core reference loop when using Include and ThenInclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my application, users can make requests for more information. I then need to be able to pull this information , but I also need to be able to see which bookings the user who made the request has already made.

I have set the following up with EF Core:

**Models:**

```
public class InfoRequest
{
    public int InfoRequestId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Booking> { get; set; }
}

public class Booking
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set }
}
```

**Context:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<InfoRequest>(builder =>
{
    builder.ToTable("inforequests");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.InfoRequestId);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<User>(builder =>
{
    builder.ToTable("userdetails");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.UserId);

    builder
        .HasMany(x => x.Bookings)
        .WithOne(x => x.User)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>(builder =>
{
    builder.ToTable("bookings");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.BookingId);
});
```

I am using the following code to pull the data I need:

```
public IQueryable<InfoRequest> GetAllInfoRequestsWithChildren()
    => this.Context.Set<InfoRequest>().AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.User)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Bookings);
```

Annoyingly, this is giving my the following self-referencing data structure which is obviously super slow:

```
InfoRequest
    -> User
        -> Booking
            -> User
                -> Booking
                    -> User
                        -> Booking
                            -> etc...
```

How can I prevent this from happening without pulling it all into memory with a `ToList()` and then removing the loop manually? I just want EF to not create a loop in the first place.

What I want is the following:

```
InfoRequest
    -> User
        -> Booking
```

Comment: In simple word! You cannot prevent this in C# code. but you stop this during JSON conversion.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with JSON. This is in the back-end of an MVC application.

Comment: Then you cannot stop it! This is EF and EF Core default behavior and no way to change this.

Comment: i am not sure but maybe explicit loading will do the trick refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data for example

Comment: also since 2.1 the added lazy loading that could make it a bit better (at least they will not load right away) but they require the use of lazy load proxies same doc as above for example.

Comment: The circular reference is normal and appropriate. What loop are you doing that is trying to traverse this? That's what you need to change.

Comment: I have posted a answer so that others with same question come to here can understand the things quickly without reading the whole comment section. Thank you all.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Except he said "I'm not doing anything with JSON".

Answer (score 4):

You cannot stop proxy creation while using **Eager Loading** in **EF/EF Core**. This is the default behavior of **EF/EF core** and no way to change this.

But may be (I didn't try out) you can stop the proxy creation for **Lazy Loading** in **EF Core >=2.1** as [EF Core documentation said](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading-without-proxies).

But you can stop `Self referencing loop` due to the proxies while you converting the entity to `JSON` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```

For more details: [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late however,
This guy saved my ass:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11564#issuecomment-664443879

I also added referencelooping.Ignore on addJsonOptions as @TanvirArjel mentioned.

However it still loops a bit but not all the way, i dont know if it has to do with the ef core version i use (3.1.23), in a new project do we use version 5+ and do not have this problem. But here do we also use profile mapper to viewModels which might save this case.